# Meteor with react: I get `^something^ is not defined` when I run the build application or run via '--production' flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

On my metero application I manage to run it without problems locally on my pc via `meteor run` command. Afterwads I build in by following theese steps:

```
cd ^project_path^
meteor build --directory ~/build
```

Then I try to test if the build was successfull by running theese steps:

```
cd ~/build/bundle/programs/server
npm install
rm -rf node_modules/bundle/fibers
npm install fibers
cd ~/build/
export PORT=8021
export ROOT_URL="http://localhost:8021"
export METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat mysettings.json)
node main.js
```

Then when I visit on my browser http://localhost:8021 I get the following error:

> me is not defined

While if I use the `--debug` param on `meteor build` then it works just fine. Do you fellows know how to figure out why does it happen.

**NOTE:**

Please keep in mind I am asking a *WAY* to figure out and not the solution, but if you have the solution it would be welcome.

Also keep in mind that I use meteor with reactjs. Also the project has been based on [pup](https://github.com/cleverbeagle/pup) boilerplate.

## Edit1

I also tried to run the app via:

```
meteor --production --settings ^a_settings_file^
```

And I get the same error.

Comment: It means somewhere you have referenced something call "me" and it is not defined. Start to look into your project (and dependencies) for something that uses "me".

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why are you trying to combine two separate frameworks into one? This does not sound like it will end well.

Comment: @Lansana The application I develop comes bundled with meteor and react together. Also meteor supports react.

Comment: That is interesting, I've never heard of the coupling before until now.

Comment: Is it possible to post your app.js file ? Do you have your project on git ?

Comment: Well this I cannot do it for now but I can make a sample app and try if I can reproduce the error.

Comment: Also the meteor does not build app.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the minifier f*** up the code and results to unwanted errors. Just remove the default one and experiment with other ones.

To remove the default minifier just do:

```
meteor remove standard-minifier-js
```

Then you can isntall the one Iused and works:

```
meteor add abernix:standard-minifier-js
```

Also according to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8822 there are may be some improvements on minifying apps.